# Laravel and ajax pass user id and role on select

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a page like this:

```
@extends('admin.master') @section('title', 'Users')
@section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>Updated At</th>
            <th>Roles</th>
            <th>Buttons</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->role}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->created_at}}</td>
                <td>{{$user->updated_at}}</td>
                <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$user->id}}">
                <select  class="required form-control form-field" name="type" onchange="role(this.value);" id="type">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose role...</option>
                    @foreach ($roles as $role)
                      <option value={{ $role->id}}>{{ $role->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                  </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o pull-left" style="color: yellow;" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateUser"></i>
                <form method="POST" action={{ url('profile/delete/' . $user->id) }}>
                {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <button type="submit" class="delete" style="border:none;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o pull-right" style="color:red;" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
    <div class="fa add-button"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x" style="color: white;" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createUser"></i></div>
</div>
@include('admin.partials.user.updateUser')
@include('admin.partials.user.createUser')
@endsection


function role(role_value) {
 $.ajax({
        url: '/test2/' + role_value,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log("wrong");
        },
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
}
```

For each user I have a row with data and dropdown with roles available. After I choose a role from dropdown I want to call a function which is ajax request that will pass selected `role_id` which works fine, however I also want to pass `user_id` from the same row as the specific dropdown I have choosen the value for. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the user id on your function like this

```
onchange="role(this.value,'{{$user->id}}');"
```

Then on your JS

```
function role(role_value,user_id) {
   //Use the user_id and pass it to your ajax
   console.log(user_id);
   $.ajax({
   ......
   });
}
```

Comment: hold on, actually it says that 'role' is undefined when I trigget onchange event

Comment: There is something wrong on your code. check the line of error. We have just added a new parameter. We didn't remove anything.

Comment: onchange="role(this.value,'{{$user->id}}');" and function role(role_value,user_id) { so it should be fine, it was working before adding it

Comment: javascript is in separate file not inside blade

Comment: I think you just misspelled the role_value.

Comment: it seems like it's fine

Answer (score 3):

Following should do the work for you :

```
onchange="role('{{$user->id}}',this.value)"
```